# Navigate from react native view to ios views in a hybrid app

Tags: ios, react-native

Hi I was wondering if anyone was able to figure out how to navigate from react native view to native ios view in a hybrid app? I can't seem to find any good documentation for this.

Comment: I just started doing this. i am going through [Native Modules Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) and [Swift Modules For React Native](http://moduscreate.com/swift-modules-for-react-native/).

Answer (score 1):

There is no official API for this in React Native, but you can write some swift/objc code to do it and call it from your React Native code.

You can read [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) about how you can expose functions from swift/objc to React Native.

Answer (score 0):

Expose your class and method to react native. 
To navigate from react native view to native view NotificationCenter is called.
[example app source code](https://github.com/pacific0009/RCTIntegration/blob/master/RCTIntegration/ViewController.swift)